Issues with values expected as scalar but with undefined row number
I am currently writing a matlab function that I have embedded in a simulink model.
Now when compiling I get the error message that simulink expect indx_p11 to be a scalar but it is a [:?,1] where I use this to extract data slices from the matrix. Similar error messages exist for the other indx_p variables.
Initially the lines with indx_p11 = zeros(1,1) was not present as I hoped to preallocate them and hence fix the dimensions. The error messages were exactly the same.
I have no idea how to fix this.
Can somebody please help?
P.S.: Inside Matlab it works as intended. Simulink seems to be stricter here but I don't know how to solve it.
function indx = GetMtrxInterval(temp,press,property_matrix)

indx = zeros(4,1);
indx_p11 = zeros(1,1);
indx_p12 = zeros(1,1);
indx_p21 = zeros(1,1);
indx_p22 = zeros(1,1);

press_intervals_idx = find(diff(property_matrix(:,2))); % contains indexes of pressure values after which the pressure changes in properties STOFF table


if press >= min(property_matrix(:,2)) && press <= max(property_matrix(:,2))
    %find slice of table with max(pressure<press)
    indx_p12 = find(press<property_matrix(:,2),1) - 1;
    indx_p11 = press_intervals_idx(find(indx_p12==press_intervals_idx,1)-1)+1;

    %find slice of table with min(pressure>press)
    indx_p21 = indx_p12 + 1;
    indx_p22 = press_intervals_idx(find(indx_p12==press_intervals_idx,1)+1);

    %find temperature interval for lower pressure slice
    if temp >= min(property_matrix(indx_p11:indx_p12,1)) && temp <= max(property_matrix(indx_p11:indx_p12,1))
        %find temperature interval for lower pressure slice
        if temp == property_matrix(indx_p11,1)
            indx_t11 = indx_p11;
            indx_t12 = indx_t11+1;
        else
            indx_t12 = indx_p11 + find(temp<=property_matrix(indx_p11:indx_p12,1),1) - 1;
            indx_t11 = indx_t12-1;
        end
    end


indx = [indx_t11; ...
    indx_t12; ...
    indx_t21; ...
    indx_t22];
end


The line indx_p11 = zeros(1,1); is doing nothing, because you're overwriting the value of the entire variable anyway with indx_p11 = press_intervals_idx(...), and since the index into press_intervals_idx is the dynamic output from find it could be anything, especially as it depends on the diff of an input which could also be anything. Presumably at some point find is returning empty or more than one index, so indx_p11 becomes nonscalar. You would have to debug to see if this is the case. You might be able to refactor your code so it doesn't depend on find like this anyway

*doing nothing [if your if condition is satisfied to run the bulk of that function]
